# Firebase storage (files) backup

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

We have a scheduled function that processes a firebase backup.

For Firestore DB, we use a built-in method - https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export

However, we also need to back up user files that are placed in the storage. I did not find a good solution for files backup, so I ended up using of `bucket.copy` method - it will copy files one by one and put them into another storage.

That worked fine for some period, but now the function experiences a timeout error (as we have a lot of files already) - `Function execution took 540026 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'`.

As the amount of files is growing every day, I am not sure how to fix the `timeout` issue. Could you please advise?

Would you recommend using another way? If so, please specify

Answer (score 0):

Increase your memory and add parameter in functions

Try below code

```
const runtimeOpts = {
  timeoutSeconds: 300,
  memory: '1GB'
}

exports.getMessages = functions.runWith(runtimeOpts).https.onCall((data, context) => {
}
```

Comment: The timeout and memory are already set as the maximum possible values. So unfortunately that is not a way to solve it